# PostgreSQL Trigger Function Call Error: "function <function> doesn't exist"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, supabase

I have a PostgreSQL trigger that fires after an `INSERT` on the `auth.users` table, calling a function `handle_new_user()` which, in turn, calls `insert_into_profiles()` to add user data to another table.

The `insert_into_profiles` function is defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_profiles(
    inp_profile_id UUID,
    inp_first_name TEXT,
    inp_last_name TEXT
)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO profiles (profile_id, first_name, last_name)
    VALUES (inp_profile_id, inp_first_name, inp_last_name);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The trigger function `handle_new_user()` is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION handle_new_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM insert_into_profiles(
        NEW.id,
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'first_name'),
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'last_name')      
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER on_auth_user_created
AFTER INSERT ON auth.users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION handle_new_user();
```

However, when the trigger fires, I encounter an error:

> function insert_into_profiles(uuid, text, text) doesn't exist.

What could be causing this issue?

> The function works fine when manually called e.g. `SELECT insert_into_profiles('12345678-1234-5678-1234-1234567890123,'Jhon','Doe');`, but within the trigger context, it seems to be unable to find the function signature.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your functions are set to `security definer`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_profiles(
    inp_profile_id UUID,
    inp_first_name TEXT,
    inp_last_name TEXT
)
RETURNS VOID
security definer
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO profiles (profile_id, first_name, last_name)
    VALUES (inp_profile_id, inp_first_name, inp_last_name);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION handle_new_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER
security definer
AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM insert_into_profiles(
        NEW.id,
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'first_name'),
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'last_name')      
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function probably is not on your `search_path`. You should always set an appropriate `search_path` on each function, so that all the tables and functions that you call in the function are in one of the schemas. For example

```
ALTER FUNCTION handle_new_user SET search_path = auth, public;
```

That will work if `insert_into_profiles()` is in schema `auth` or in schema `public`.

Comment: Supabase  uses `public` already as one of the default search paths. I clearly provide in my `handle_new_user()` that the trigger needs to fire on `auth.users` where i explicitly define the schema. So your answer didn't help. However, you answer made my think about explicitly defining the schema every time I address a table, function, trigger. This made the error go away, but now I have `permission denied for table profiles`

Comment: That's another way to solve the same problem. So my solution will work as well (and be safer). You just have to set the `search_path` so that the function you are trying to call is on it.

Comment: @Laurenz: How is setting a `search_path` "safer" than explicitly qualifying each table/function reference?

Comment: It is easy to forget a function call. And then operators, data types etc. are resolved using the `search_path` as well. See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/) for a drastic example.

Comment: @Joerie, this `permission denied for table profiles` is telling you the problem. The user the function is running as does not have INSERT permission on the table`profiles`.